# Artificial neural network presented with unclassified inputs

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I am trying to classify portions of time series data using a feed forward neural network using 20 neurons in a single hidden layer, and 3 outputs corresponding to the 3 events I would like to be able to recognize.  There are many other things that I could classify in the data (obviously), but I don't really care about them for the time being.  Neural network creation and training has been performed using Matlab's neural network toolbox for pattern recognition, as this is a classification problem.

In order to do this I am sequentially populating a moving window, then inputting the window into the neural network.  The issue I have is that I am obviously not able to classify and train every possible shape the time series takes on.  Due to this, I typically get windows filled with data that look very different from the windows I used to train the neural network, but still get outputs near 1.

Essentially, the 3 things I trained the ANN with are windows of 20 different data sets that correspond to shapes that would correspond to steady state, a curve that starts with a negative slope and levels off to 0 slope (essentially the left half side of a parabola that opens upwards), and a curve corresponding to 0 slope that quickly declines (right half side of a parabola that opens downwards).

Am I incorrect in thinking that if I input data that doesn't correspond to any of the items I trained the ANN with it should output values near 0 for all outputs?

Or is it likely due to the fact that these basically cover all the bases of steady state, increasing and decreasing, despite large differences in slope, and therefore something is always classified?

I guess I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Have I understood you correctly if I believe that you've only introduced the NN with input values which should make the output value equal to 1? In other words: have you trained the network on input values that should output 0?

Answer (score 0):

## Neural network output values

A neural network may not guarantee specific output values if these input values / expected output values were presented during the training period.

> A neural network will not consistently output 0 for untrained input values.

A solution is to simply present the network with an array of input values that should result in the network outputting 0.